# XCode8 / Swift will not let me set a textField's text equal to a String?

Tags: ios, swift, string, textfield

I am very new to iOS application programming (started learning just under a week ago!) so I'm sure what I'm asking is very obvious!

So I am working on an Application for my work study position and cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Basically, all I want to do is check to make sure each field is filled in before allowing the user to carry on. I did a similar thing in another view controller to check to see if what was entered is equal to the password I set for the program (I am sure there is a better way to do this, but because I'm self learning and it's my first application, I'm not worried too much. I have a whole year to polish it!)

Here is the code for that (if you have suggestions that may improve it, feel free, but for the most part, I'm just trying to figure out why this worked and the other code is not)

```
@IBAction func enterPassword(_ sender: Any) {

    pw = password.text!
    let message = "Incorrect Password"

    if(pw == "RISE")
    {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToMenu", sender: self)
    }
    else {
        incorrect.text = message
    }
}
```

**please note that the variable "pw" is a global variable and is declared outside of the class. Password and incorrect are both labels previously declared as well.**

Here is the code that is in question. I do not understand why I am getting an error for this. it is "thread 1: exc_bad_instruction". I'm honestly not even sure what this error means so if you happen to know what it means, please enlighten me! I included all the code for the viewController with the issue.

```
import UIKit


var studName = " "
class CreateViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var ID: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var YR: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var test: UILabel!


@IBAction func endCreate(_ sender: Any) {
    studName = name.text!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am really uncertain and confused. I am pretty good at coding in Java and C++ so I never expected to have issues learning but it's totally different and is taking a lot longer than I expected (It took me about a week to learn C#...).

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: 
(I need 10 reputation to post more than two links, so I deleted the error. lol I guess I'll go answer some questions or something)

[Click here to see StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Eb6.png)

[Click here to see Connection to NAME (note I reconnected it and used all caps, error is still an issue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzvlT.png)

if there is any other information that may help you understand, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error you are having and where it is happening?

Comment: Without seeing more, it sounds like your name outlet is not connected.

Comment: Question could be shorter to attract more attention. Anyway, in which line you get error?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that `password.text` is `nil`, and your force unwrapping is causing an error. `UILabel` is initialized with a `nil` `text`, not `""`.

Comment: @BJHStudios It is definitely connected, I just reconnected it.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan It is the "studName = name.text!" line

Comment: @BallpointBen The error is not with the password part, I showed that to explain why I was confused I was getting an error with the "studName = name.text!" line

Comment: @CyrilIvarGarcia I posted a screenshot! hopefully it helps you understand

Comment: That error is happening because at the time you are trying to access it either name or name.text is nil. Both are being force unwrapped, so the application crashes if they are nil. This still indicates an error in connecting the name iboutlet (not the ibaction). Can you post a screenshot of your storyboard showing the connections please?

Comment: @BJHStudios I posted a screenshot of the Storyboard and connections. Let me know if I did a bad job on that, I am still new and am not 100% sure what exactly you need to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you are experiencing the crash on this line

```
studName = name.text!
```

? (If not could you please include the stack trace to indicate where you are getting an issue?)

It looks like either `name` is `nil`, or `text` is `nil` both of which are being force unwrapped here. So either you haven't connected this text field properly in interface builder, or there is just no text in it.

My general rule is (and I'm sure people will disagree with this):

> NEVER use `!`

Such a simple rule :)

I reason this that, force unwrapping an optional variable is never (very, very rarely) required, and implies an assumption of a value that was clearly intended to be allowed to be nil (otherwise it would not be optional). Typically, if you find yourself using a `!` on one of your own variables, consider refactoring the variable to not be optional, otherwise make heavy use of optional binding and/or guard statements to avoid forcing things.

(My one main caveat for this is creating instance variables that require self as a parameter for initialisation. Where the instance variable is an implicitly unwrapped optional, but is set immediately after the call to super's initialiser, and never again)

Also, while it works and is valid code, it is not typical to use global variables for things like `studName`, this should be an instance variable in your controller.

Do feel free to shout if you have any other questions about this (or anything iOS/swift). If you're just getting started, I can't recommend http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p highly enough! A thorough rundown of all core iOS technologies and design patterns.

**EDIT for comment**

In this case you could avoid using this `!` by making your variable optional, you could declare `studName` using

```
var studName: String? = " "
```

this makes it an optional variable which will allow you to assign a nil value to it.

If you are sure you don't want it to be nil, you could also do your assignment as

```
studName = name.text ?? " "
```

This will check the value of `name.text` and if it is not `nil` assign to `studName`, otherwise it will assign the value on the right `" "`. It essentially allows you to provide an default value for an assignment that is not optional. It is shorthand for:

```
if let text = name.text {
    studName = text
} else {
    studName = " "
}
```

Comment: Yep that's where I'm having the issue. my app is crashing no matter what my textfield, name has in it. someone else said it wasn't connected, I'll try doing that again. But while I'm messing around with that, how can I not use "!"? I would love to not use it, but I get an error if I don't.

Comment: Reconnecting it did not work. Is there anything else from my program that can help you figure out why the app is crashing on that line?

Comment: @AmberRebeccaHowe Hmmm, could you possibly add a `print(studName)`, `print(name)`, and `print(name.text)` above the line that crashes, that should shed some light?

Comment: I encounter a break with both print(name) and print(name.text). I tried reconnecting once more but it isn't working. :(

Comment: In which case it seems `name` is nil, if you try `print(name?)` do you get `Optional(nil)`?

Comment: !!! you got it! I played around with the code making the variable optional and the app no longer crashes! thanks so much!!

Comment: Wooohooo! Glad we got it sorted. Do shout if anything else come up :)

Answer (score 0):

Great start. Here is how I would write it:

```
@IBAction func enterPassword(_ sender: Any) {

        //Make sure we trim off any white space or new lines and then optionally bind the text in the text field.
        guard let passwordText = self.password.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines) else {
            self.incorrect.text = "Please enter a password."
            return
        }
        //Make sure text is not a blank string eg: ""
        guard !passwordText.isEmpty else {
            self.incorrect.text = "Please enter a password."
            return
        }
        //Make sure it is the password we want.
        guard passwordText == "ThePassword" else {
            self.incorrect.text = "Not the correct password."
            return
        }

        //Success! Do other stuff here. Like perform a segue.

}
```

And just for good measure and a little fun. Here is a great extension on UITextField to provide a nice little shake animation if anything is invalid.

```
extension UITextField {
   func shake(times T: Int, distance D: CGFloat) {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.06, animations: {
         self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: D, y: 0)
      }) { (didComplete) in
         UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.06, animations: {
             self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
         }, completion: { (didComplete) in

            guard T > 0 else {
                return
            }
            self.shake(times: T - 1, distance: D)
        })
      }
   }
}
```

[George Green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175289/george-green) is right. Force unwrapping in Swift is considered a code smell. Always optionally bind an optional value. Makes for a little more verbose code but keeps everything safe.

Comment: Unwrapping is not a code smell but a legitimate operation. You just have to decide correctly when you can force the unwrapping and recognize the crash when it happens.

Comment: @Sulthan Not according to the first [item in the first Google search result](https://cocoacasts.com/five-signs-of-code-smell-in-swift/)  for "Swift code smells"

Comment: The blog post does not say *never use forced unwrapping*. It says *use with caution*. The operator exists in Swift for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

There you go... here I See the problem. I removed Outlet to the TextField and immediately I saw that error.
[image: See error here]

Please make sure you connect the `IBOutlet` properly and it works perfectly as shown below.
[image: See how it works]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how to connect it...? I am holding control and dragging it over to the code and selecting outlet. I have a feeling there might be something else wrong with it...

Comment: @AmberRebeccaHowe can you send me the screenshot of the TextField IBOutlet connection (Both on Textfield and Code as well).

Answer (score -1):

Firstly,

Take an Outlet for the `TextField` as shown below

```
 // MARK:- IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!`
```

Take a Button & assign `IBAction` for the the button, "`passwordCheck`" in this case.
You can compare `TextField` text to string as shown below

```
// MARK:- IBActions
@IBAction func passwordCheck(_ sender: Any) {
    if passwordTextField.text == "RISE" {
        print("perform Segue")
    } else {
        print("Do nothing")
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubts...

Comment: The password code works, actually! I'll take your suggestions into consideration. Is there anything with the second portion of code I added that you can help me with? the line "studName = name.text!" is making my app crash.

Comment: @AmberRebeccaHowe To my knowledge there is no problem in the section. To make sure I have done exactly what you have done, It worked for me. See the link Below.

Comment: @AmberRebeccaHowe I am guessing your outlet might not hooked up or having multiple outlets do verify once.